# .net: Shorten a string, store it as a new string, and later 'rehydrate'

Tags: .net, forms-authentication

I have an application that stores each user role as a comma-delimited string in the userData portion of the forms authentication ticket.

We have run into a situation where a user was part of many roles, and those roles all have long names. There is a maximum # of characters that you can put into the userData, likely a limitation of cookies.

So, is there a low-cost way I can shorten this string and 'rehydrate' it later?

Unforunately, the userData portion of the ticket is a string - if it were an object I could store it as byte[] and use System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString() later.

I guess this is really a question about being able to shorten a string, store it as a string, and rehydrate it later without losing its original value.

Comment: I don't recommend pouring water into your program.

Comment: Ok, so maybe 'decompress' would have been a better term!

Comment: How do you define "low-cost"?

Comment: Wait a second. Are you putting *security roles* into the cookie in plaintext? If so, you may have larger issues than just running out of space.

Comment: Yep, they are going into the forms authentication ticket. It's encrypted. This is not an uncommon technique.

Answer (score 4):

How about just using the roleId ?  If setup properly you could even OR these together to form a single integer containing all the roles.

Comment: That would be my answer, though that would probably affect quite a bit of his other code.

Comment: +1 Bitwise is very appropriate for this situation assuming roleids are mutually exclusive.

Comment: We use it exactly same way "1:12" where 1 represents role and 12 represents user id and it can go for years to pass the max limit. There is no shorter method because in order to use compression you should have good amount of repetation in your string.

Answer (score 3):

So, string compression?

I'd start by looking at System.IO.Compression

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.aspx

Comment: Though, with short strings, <500, characters it'll probably be hard to find a way to compress it, and actually be of a benefit.

Comment: This doesn't sound very low-cost.

Comment: +1, I just did some arbitrary testing with text data from 500 bytes to 4096 bytes (the max in IE for cookie size), using gzip and then base64, and still got a %10-%40 size decrease. Not bad.

Comment: Did your test data look like @ScottE's? If it was just all 'a's then it definitely will produce those results. :)

Comment: FWIW base64 ADDS overhead. I recently saw an article mentioning this related to Azure Queue's limit of "8KB" but is really closer to 6KB due to them converting your string to base64.